# How to assign keys in the keyboard?

Tags: 10.04, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-netbook

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 netbook version and I want to assign my windows key on the keyboard to preform the same function as it as in windows (minimize all app and open favorite). Now the key is not assign to anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

o into sstem settings>Shortcuts and Gestures (might be different for Ubuntu as i'm using Kubuntu) and edit the keybindings. the windows key will show up as "meta"

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the gear in the top-right corner of your screen.
2. Click System Settings.
3. Click Keyboard.
4. Go to the Shortcuts tab.

Comment: I dont have this option but i got "keyboard shortcuts" when i click on it I can't find the option that i want to assign

Comment: There is a + button that you can create custom shortcuts with.